# UWP/Windows How to get current titlebar color

Tags: javascript, windows, uwp, winjs, titlebar

```
var appView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.getForCurrentView();
console.log(appView.titleBar.backgroundColor); // <- this is null by default
```

So the question is - is there any way to determine an exact title bar background color in case it was not specified explicitly.
In this case it will be one of the following:

- white for light theme,
- black for dark theme,
- accent color if `Colors -> Show color on title bar` is `On`.

I need that in a JavaScript app.

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to get the color if you didn't specified it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks Elvis! That's a pity.